# Latest unique item from a SP list column

Tags: list-view, splistitem, view, unique

I have a SP2010 list.This list has a choice column.

I want to create a view with the unique items(latest one) from this column.

How to achieve this?

Comment: What you mean by latest one from the choice column? You have only the list item Modified value.

Comment: @amal hashim I want to display only the unique items from this choice column.These unique items must be the latest one created.

Comment: @Amal Hashim For eg: Consider the "Status" column has the choices "Started" and "Completed".There are 2 items having the status "Started" and 2 items having the status "completed".
I want to display the latest item(based on creation date) which has the status "Started" and latest one which has the status "Completed".

Answer (score 2):

You can create a view and set following properties

1. Group By = Choice Field
2. Sort = Modified Descending Order

Now you can open the view using SharePoint Designer and modify the XSLT to limit the items per group to one.

Answer (score 0):

I displayed the list in DVWP and replaced the "Rows" variable in "dvt_1" xsl template section using the below XSLT:

> xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[not(@Columnname=following::Row/@Columnname)]"/>

This helped me to display the unique values from the choice column and i used sorting to display the items as i required.